# How To Set Servlet Init Parameter in Apache Sling?

Tags: java, aem, sling

I have a shared Java OSGi bundle that is used in other projects. This my shared lib requires some configuration that other projects will have to config it via servlet context init parameter.

Currently my JSP/Servlet, Spring/SpringBoot, Struts users can set required configurations in web.xml, or in `@SpringBootApplication` as below:

JSP/Servlet, Spring, Struts app:

```
// web.xml
<init-param>  
  <param-name>my_config</param-name>  
  <param-value>value</param-value>  
</init-param>
```

SpringBoot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    
    @Bean 
    public ServletContextInitializer initializer() { 
      return new ServletContextInitializer() { 

        @Override 
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException { 
            servletContext.setInitParameter("my_config", "value"); 
        } 
      }; 
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to make my shared lib to work on Apache Sling but I don't know how to set servlet init parameter in Apache Sling. I am just a newbie of Apache Sling.

Comment: Can you tell us a little, what you want to reach? Maybe the SlingServlet is not the right answer. As Sling is built on top of OSGi (Apache Felix), you could as example also integrate a Servlet via the OSGi Whiteboard Pattern. Or even integrate with the underlying Servlet Container (Jetty). But of course you could also do a SlingServlet, and then the configuration would be OSGi based.

Comment: PS: As you used a SpringBoot example, I assumed that you are probably more interested in interoperability, and not so much in the specifics of the SlingServlet. Actually Sling itself is mainly one big servlet, that does a lot of URL-routing based on content and configuration. Then your SlingServlet is just one of many endpoints, that Sling may use to fulfill the request. A SlingServlet is an OSGi component, that is used by Sling - it is not directly connected to the Servlet-Container. It has also a somehow compatible/similar, but different API.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to have Sling run in a servlet container as a WAR and provide init-param as usual in `web.xml` - see [Sling configuration documentation](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html#web-application).

Getting something like a Spring Boot application to work with Sling would be too much work, as they tend to use their own servlet container, classloader, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When running a Sling standalone app, osgi HttpService that loads sling (and handles everything http before sling) provides a way to dynamically register servlets:

```
 httpService.registerServlet("/myservlet", servlet, initparams, context);
```

you can put a key value pair in initparams, The Http Service will call the servlet's init method before returning.

you would want to register your container's DispatcherServlet (or equivalent) here and delegate further url resolution to it. [see documentation](http://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.http.html#org.osgi.service.http.HttpService.registerServlet-String-javax.servlet.Servlet-Dictionary-HttpContext-).

Be aware that this will bypass sling's `handleSecurity` method (and so all sling's security checks) but code invoked here can have access to jcr and almost everything in the osgi container. Unless you have very compelling reasons to, don't do this.